# repeat job in spring batch (and stop, start)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I wanna perform repetitive tasks using Spring batch.

For example, stop and restart a job that outputs the minimum value in the database table using the controller.

(never mind the logic that the step executes)

or is it impossible using spring batch..?? then let me know another way (like @Scheduled)

```
@Configuration
public class someJob{

    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

// make it repeat infinitely
    @Bean
    public Job job() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("job").start(step()).build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step").tasklet(some_task).build();
    }
}

-----------------------------------------------------
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/control")
public class Controller {


    @PostMapping("/restart")
    public void restart() {
        // restart job
    }

    @PostMapping("/stop/{jobId}")
    public void stop() {
        // stop job
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Enable Scheduling**

You can enable scheduling simply by adding the `@EnableScheduling` annotation to the main application class.

**Scheduling Tasks**

Scheduling a task is as simple as annotating a method with `@Scheduled` annotation.

In the below example, `execute()` method is scheduled to run every minute. `execute()` method will invoke the desired job.

```
public class ScheduledJob {

    @Setter
    private boolean isJobEnabled = true;

    @Autowired
    private Job job;

    @Autowired
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
    public void execute() throws Exception {
        if (isJobEnabled) {
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addString("time", LocalDateTime.now().toString()).toJobParameters();

            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);

            System.out.println("Job Exit Status :: " + execution.getExitStatus());
        }
    }

}
```

Value for `isJobEnabled` can be toggled using REST API call as shown below to enable / disable execution of job.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/job")
public class RestController {

    @Autowired
    private ScheduledJob scheduledJob;

    @PostMapping("/enable")
    public void enable() {
        scheduledJob.setJobEnabled(true);
    }

    @PostMapping("/disable")
    public void disable() {
        scheduledJob.setJobEnabled(false);
    }

}
```

*Please note that only Job Execution has been restricted using this approach but `execute()` method will continue to execute based on defined schedule*

**Types of Scheduling**

1. Scheduling with fixed rate

   > `execute()` method can be scheduled to run with a fixed interval using `fixedRate` parameter.
   >
   > ```
   > @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000)
   > ```
2. Scheduling with fixed delay

   > `execute()` method can be scheduled to run with a fixed delay between the completion of the last invocation and the start of the next, using `fixedDelay` parameter.
   >
   > ```
   > @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 2000)
   > ```
3. Scheduling with initial delay and fixed rate / fixed delay

   > `initialDelay` parameter with `fixedRate` and `fixedDelay` to delay the first execution.
   >
   > ```
   > @Scheduled(fixedRate = 2000, initialDelay = 5000)
   > ```
   >
   > ```
   > @Scheduled(fixedDelay= 2000, initialDelay = 5000)
   > ```
4. Scheduling with cron

   > `execute()` method can be scheduled to run based on cron expression using `cron` parameter.
   >
   > ```
   > @Scheduled(cron = "0 * * * * *")
   > ```